# Why does this compile in VS 2015 but not in IDEOne?

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void);

void foo(int repeatCount) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++) {
        printf("\nHello World\n");
    }
}

int  main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("main");
}
```

This is intended to be C, not C++. The file in VS is saved as a .c file, the program in IDEOne is configured as a C file.

The prototype doesn't match the function definition.

However, it does compile in VS 2015. Warning Level 3 does give a warning. [image]

Comment: Hey nice question! However, I do not see why you are mixing [tag:C++] here. Probably because of the function overloading feature!

Comment: I'm not mixing anything. It's all C.

Comment: Because: bad compiler. Don't use Visual Studio for C programming. Where you read 2015 it should actually say 1990. It seems Microsoft made a typo during marketing, since their C compiler is from 1990.

Comment: @Lundin it's it's actually from 1990 then it should catch that classic C error, but it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe it is just plain bad then. In either case, it is not a standard compliant compiler.

Comment: @Lundin : The worst part is that there is not a compiler flag to catch function overloading..

Comment: MSVC is not a real C compiler. It doesn't even support some C99 features because MS stated they'll never write a C99 compiler and will only introduce some C99 support into their C++ compiler

Comment: Weird. The error is what you'd expect to see from a pre-90 C compiler, something around the K&R vintage, where function declarations didn't have parameters. Problem is, the `void` type hadn't been invented yet. I guess MSVC just ignores it, since it's basically a C++ compiler with a "C mode" and the `void` is optional there, having the same meaning as an empty arg list. Anyway, as Lundin obliquely suggests, if you want to compile C code, get yourself a real C compiler. Microsoft doesn't make one. Clang and Gnu are both good choices.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, you're not the first person to have identified this bug. It existed way back on VC++ 6. http://www.drdobbs.com/bug-of-the-month/184416256 (at the bottom of the page, search for HMACHINE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because VS studio doesn't conform to the Standard C and uses its own compiler.

With Standard C you should see something like this:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ gcc -Wall main.c
main.c:5:6: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
 void foo(int repeatCount) {
      ^
main.c:3:6: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
 void foo(void);
      ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:14:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

---

> What compiler does VS use?

The compiler is named as Microsoft C/C++ Compiler. The cl.exe is a tool that controls the Microsoft C and C++ compilers and linker. There are other compilers you can use: Intel C and C++ Compilers, which is automatically configured in Visual Studio after installation.

Comment: What compiler does VS use? How is it different?

Comment: @nicomp updated. Launch time for me, hope this helps!